# ros2 on raspberry pi

Tags: ros2, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to cross compile ROS2 Bouncy for a Raspberry pi 3, without success.

I downloaded the raspbian tools from here https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools

I'm using the `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64` toolchain.

This is my rpi3_toolchain.cmake file

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

# define some paths 
set(RASPBERRY_TOOLS_PATH /home/asoragna/repos/raspberrypi3/tools/arm-bcm2708)
set(RASPBERRY_ROOT_FS /home/asoragna/repos/raspberrypi3/rootfs)
set(RASPBERRY_ROS2_WS /home/asoragna/ros2/raspberry_sdk_ws)

# specify the cross compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${RASPBERRY_TOOLS_PATH}/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${RASPBERRY_TOOLS_PATH}/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${RASPBERRY_ROOT_FS})

# where is the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
  ${RASPBERRY_ROOT_FS}
  ${RASPBERRY_TOOLS_PATH}/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/install
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# This assumes that pthread will be available on the target system
# (this emulates that the return of the TRY_RUN is a return code "0"
set(THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG "0"
  CACHE STRING "Result from TRY_RUN" FORCE)
```

Then I build using colcon

```
colcon \
    build \
    --merge-install \
    --cmake-force-configure \
    --cmake-args \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`pwd`/rpi3_toolchain.cmake \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
    -DTHIRDPARTY=ON \
    -DBUILD_TESTING=0
```

The error I get is in the `rcutils` package:

```
In file included from /home/asoragna/ros2/raspberry_sdk_ws/src/ros2/rcutils/include/rcutils/allocator.h:26:0,
                 from /home/asoragna/ros2/raspberry_sdk_ws/src/ros2/rcutils/include/rcutils/error_handling.h:31,
                 from /home/asoragna/ros2/raspberry_sdk_ws/src/ros2/rcutils/src/error_handling.c:22:
/home/asoragna/ros2/raspberry_sdk_ws/src/ros2/rcutils/include/rcutils/macros.h:60:32: error: unknown type name ‘_Thread_local’
   #define RCUTILS_THREAD_LOCAL _Thread_local
```

DO you have any idea about how to solve this issue ? I tried different tutorials on the web but they are quite old and not easily applicable to ros2 bouncy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303988/ros2-on-raspberry-pi/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-09-24**:
I never ran into this issue. But as this is flag not present in your toolchain, can you try to replace the line 60 of macro.h by

```
#define RCUTILS_THREAD_LOCAL_PTHREAD 1
#undef RCUTILS_THREAD_LOCAL
```

To see if that solves the issue ? Does this toolchain support C11?

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-09-24**:
You can also check out https://github.com/esteve/ros2_raspbian_tools which is a nice tutorial on cross-compiling for RPi.
Or it is the link you were thinking when you said it is not for Bouncy ?

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-09-24**:
https://github.com/esteve/ros2_raspbian_tools is not working for Bouncy. I will try asap the change you suggested.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-09-24**:
Ok I made the change you suggested, but I get a new error in ament_index_cpp:

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++14’`

I think this is due to the toolchain being too old

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-09-24**:
Yeah.. Any reason to use this one instead of a more up to date one ? Can you give the version: `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version` ?

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-09-24**:
`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Linaro GCC 5.2-2015.11-2) 5.2.1 20151005`

There are no reasons at all for using it, simply it was the one provided by the official raspbian toolkits repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved all my issues by using an up to date version of `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++`.
Thank you @pokitoz for your help.

On the Raspberry, with Raspbian Stretch, this is the compiler which is already installed

```
# arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
```

So I installed it on my laptop https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=g%2B%2B-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++-6-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

There exists also a more recent version (7.2) but I have not tried if it works.

This is the rpi_toolchainfile.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-6)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-6)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/install
)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)


# This assumes that pthread will be available on the target system
# (this emulates that the return of the TRY_RUN is a return code "0"
set(THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG "0"
  CACHE STRING "Result from TRY_RUN" FORCE)
```

This is the running script

```
colcon \
    build \
    --merge-install \
    --cmake-force-configure \
    --cmake-args \
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`pwd`/rpi_toolchainfile.cmake \
    -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON \
    -DTHIRDPARTY=ON \
    -DBUILD_TESTING=0 \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_RPATH="`pwd`/build/poco_vendor/poco_external_project_install/lib/;`pwd`/build/libyaml_vendor/libyaml_install/lib/"
```

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-09-25**:
Great! So you stopped using a sysroot file? Or the new toolchain you are using already have the rasbian sysroot?

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-09-25**:
Yes, apparently is not required. This is something I will investigate for sure, as when I cross compiled ros for another system I didn't manage to make it work without the sysroot

**Comment by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) on 2018-09-25**:
Yes, the python dependencies are hard to meet without a sysroot. Or you need to ignore the python packages.

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2018-09-25**:
I'm ignoring python and test packages